# True or false: A capacitor stores energy for ½ a cycle and gives it up on the other half, the net energy is zero

Tags: capacitor, discharge, charge

I'm hoping someone can give me some more information so that I can confidently answer this question. . . True or false: A capacitor stores energy for ½ a cycle and gives it up on the other half, the net energy is zero.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the EE.SE. What did you tried?

Comment: The net energy what? The net energy delivered to the capacitor over 1 cycle at AC steady state? Yes, it's zero.

Comment: I was asking the same question Photon. This is a question from a study guide on Electricity and Magnetism, and I feel as though there isn't enough information. I just wanted a second (or multiples thereof) opinion.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question as unclear. As you can see you are getting conflicting answers. You need to provide a schematic showing how the capacitor is connected.

Comment: Such a question is completely pointless as long as there is no definition of the whole circuit and input signal(s)

Comment: The statement COULD start like so: "Connect a capacitor to a 60Hz sine voltage source."  In that case the statement is false.

Answer (score 2):

FALSE!   But it's a trick question.   (Or, perhaps the author has misconceptions about how capacitors work, and their book has errors?)

Was the answer supposed to be false?   Yet the net energy is actually zero, that part's true.  The question's *reasoning* is wrong, the number "½" is wrong, so the answer given in the back of the book had better be "false."

It's a subtle point, so perhaps the author is confused and thinks that "1/2" is correct, when it should actually be "1/4."   Or, the author is using a trick question to expose the student's ignorance.

The correct answer is: "one-half cycle is wrong, it's supposed to be 1/4!"

In detail: the capacitor's coulombs and joules are proportional to the potential-diff across its terminals, and note well: for AC sine voltage, this value goes to zero twice per cycle.   In other words, capacitors AREN'T charged on the first half-cycle and discharged on the second.   Instead, they're charged on the first quarter-cycle and discharged on the second quarter-cycle, then the process repeats a second time.  (After the first half-cycle both the energy and the charge are not maximum.  Instead both have returned to zero!)

When a capacitor is connected to a sine AC voltage source, energy moves back and forth between source and capacitor, twice per cycle.  Not once.

Examine the waveform for the positive half-cycle of current: when current starts out at zero, the capacitor voltage is at negative max, and the capacitor is already charged.  During the half-cycle of positive current, the capacitor voltage rises to zero, then rises to positive maximum  ...and when it rises to zero, that's a discharge.  The capacitor discharges in the first quarter-cycle of the positive current pulse. (And then charges opposite during the second quarter-cycle.)

Comment: Why is 1/2 wrong?

Comment: @Chu It should be false because as the amplitude of the wave increases you charge, as the amplitude decreases you discharge. So zero, up, maximum, down, zero. <-- The energy in the capacitor is now = 0. There's nothing from this half cycle that affects the next half  cycle (with ideal components -> no lag), you're just charging again (with other polarity) and then discharging again. The 1/2 is probably only mentioned because of the equation for energy in a charged capacitor and has absolutely nothing to do with which half of a wave it discharges on. - Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @HarrySvensson If your talking about current, then the capacitor keeps charging for the entire +ve half cycle and discharges back to zero over the entire -ve half cycle. I don't see how the 'reasoning' can be wrong - there's no reasoning in the question as far as I can see, just statement of facts.

Comment: @Chu I was talking about voltage, since (1/2)(c)(v^2) = energy in a capacitor. And as the v^2 terms goes to 0 after a half cycle, the energy in the capacitor is equal to 0. So the reasoning that half the energy is given back in other half of the cycle has nothing to do with the equation I just mentioned and is therefor false. The (1/2) in (1/2)(c)(v^2) is because of how capacitors work.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I think you and Chu and wbeaty are all making assumptions about how the capacitor is used in a circuit, without making those assumptions clear. Is the capacitor connected directly to the ac source or is the context include a rectifier? We don't know; the question is unclear.

Comment: >Why is 1/2 wrong?  @Chu it's supposed to be 1/4 cycles.   For the positive half-cycle, the capacitor charges on the first 1/4 cycle, discharges on the second quarter-cycle.  But the statement said half-cycle, so it's false. Then for the negative half cycle, repeat the same process. Volts, coulombs, and joules hit zero *twice*, so if we apply one full AC cycle, we get: charge, discharge, charge, discharge. (Capacitors DON'T charge on the first half-cycle!) Correct statement: A capacitor stores energy in the first quarter-cycle and gives it up in the second quarter-cycle  ...net energy is zero.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson yes unclear (author seems to have hidden assumptions; talking as if the charge and discharge process are symmetrical.)   Heh, if the power supply was an AC sine current-source, then the capacitor may have an initial DC potential, a net offset voltage.  The voltage across the capacitor could even remain positive during both half-cycles!

Comment: 1/2 a cycle isn't *wrong*, if you allow that time to be discontinuous...

Answer (score 1):

True.

The energy stored in a capacitor is given by \$ U = \frac {1}{2}C V^2 \$.

If the average energy is increasing then V would be increasing too.

[image]

*Figure 1. An example circuit. [Physics and radio electronics](https://www.physics-and-radio-electronics.com/electronic-devices-and-circuits/rectifier/halfwaverectifier.html).*

The circuit of Figure 1 gives a common example (which doesn't quite match the charge for ½ cycle requirement of the title as the charge current is a shorter pulse). If the net energy is not zero then the average voltage would fall or rise forever.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!**

It's true *or* false.

When connected across a sine-wave AC supply an ideal capacitor stores energy while the voltage is increasing in magnitude and releases energy when the voltage is decreasing in magnitude. so half the tlong period will ne equal
ime it's storing and half the time releasing.

But the it's not a continuous half of the AC cycle, it's store for 1/4 release for 1/4 store for 1/4 release for 1/4, so not 1/2 and 1/2

Also if the wave-form is not not symmetrical the time spent storing and releasing may not be even.

However the total energy stored and released over a cycle will balance (to zero)

Answer (score 1):

If biased around DC, the capacitor stores energy as the voltage increases in magnitude (either positive or negative), and the capacitor gives up energy as the voltage returns to zero. Thus 1/4 cycle is store, 1/4 cycle is discharge, this occurring for each **1/2** cycle.

If biased asymmetrically, then the timing changes.

Answer (score 0):

No energy is lost in a purely reactive load, which a capacitor is. Over time for any repeating voltage signal with no average bias, the cap’s average charge will be zero. That is, the net charge is the integral of applied voltage over time. Zero integral => no charge.

Now, whether it ‘returns’ its energy in 1/2 cycle depends on the waveform. If it’s perfectly symmetrical, then yes (with a lagging I of course.) Otherwise, no.

More here because it’s late and typing math is a pain: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng2.html

Comment: But the given statement says that the capacitor *doesn't* return its energy in 1/2 cycle.   That's why it's false (assuming sine AC cycles.)  The statement says it returns its energy after one complete cycle: charging on the first half, and discharging on the second.  False.  The "1/2" is wrong, it's supposed to be "1/4."

Comment: Consider a triangle wave, analyze the charge over time.

Answer (score -2):

yes it is true.because the basic working of capacitor is that it charges for one half cycle and discharges the energy that stored in 1 half cycle.for ideal capacitor net energy is Zero.

Answer (score -2):

I talked to my Manufacturing instructor, and he said a capacitor would hold a charge until the energy was released. Whatever percentage of charge capacity was there would will be present until discharged.